# Reducing frame-rate with Python OpenCV VideoCapture

Tags: python, video-capture, opencv

I have a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian 9. I have OpenCV 4.0.1 installed. I have a USB Webcam attached. The Raspberry is headless, I connect with `ssh <user>@<IP> -X`. The goal is to get a real-time video stream on my client computer.

The issue is that there is a considerable lag of around 2 seconds. Also the stream playback is unsteady, this means slow and then quick again.

My guess is that SSH just cannot keep up with the camera's default 30fps. I therefore try to reduce the frame-rate as I could live with a lower frame-rate as long as there's no noticeable lag. My own attempts to reduce the frame rate have not worked.

My code, commented the parts that I tried myself to reduce the frame-rate but did not work.

```
import cv2
#import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 5)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    #time.sleep(1)

    #cv2.waitKey(100)

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**what I tried to reduce the frame rate:**

1. I tried to set `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 5)` (also tried 10 or 1). If I then `print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))` it gives me the frame-rate I just set but it has no effect on the playback.
2. I tried to use `time.sleep(1)` in the while loop but it has no effect on the video.
3. I tried to use a second `cv2.waitKey(100)` in the while loop as suggested here on Quora: https://qr.ae/TUSPyN , but this also has no effect.

### edit 1 (time.wait and waitKey indeed work):

As pointed out in the comment, `time.sleep(1)` and `cv2.waitKey(1000)` should both work and indeed they did after all. It was necessary to put these at the end of the while loop, after `cv2.imshow()`.

As pointed out in the first comment, it might be better to choose a different setup for streaming media, which is what I am looking at now to get rid of the lag.

### edit 2 (xpra instead of ssh -X):

We found out that even after all attempts to reduce the frame rate, `ssh -X` was sill laggy. We found [xpra](https://xpra.org/) to be a lot quicker, i.e. not requiring any lowering of the frame rate or resolution and not having noticeable lag.

Comment: I am not sure about your case but for the present work I am doing, we use webRTC to stream to a media Server (Janus) and then that Media server in turn streams to a UDP socket. Where we use GStreamer and OpenCV to pick up frame by frame. In general, it was a pain to make the whole thing work. However, once it starts working it does produce good frames.

Comment: I don't see how an acquisition loop with a timed sleep of 1 second in it could possibly fail to reduce a 30 fps rate down to 1 fps?

Comment: After each cap.read()
 call:  cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) + 10)

Comment: And do not set cv2.waitKey(1). Wait time must be 1000 / fps.

Comment: Naively sleeping in your code may just make you process the same frame rate just more slowly, i.e. for _t_ loops of your code you'd process _t_ frames but those will be just the frames that came into the capture much faster, and ultimately you are then lagging behind the frame rate. In that scenario you're simply not processing the frames at the rate that they are coming. I can only assume that `cv2.waitKey` throttles back the actual frame acquisition then.